# How to say that I am eating above something?

Tags: prepositions

In my country we are used to saying *I am eating above/over something*.

**Example:** you are eating pizza at your desk where is a keyboard. You have it in your hand so it is not on the keyboard, but above... lifted.

What is the right word, or is there any other way to say it?

Is it *at*?

Comment: You had it right: *I am eating over my keyboard*.

Comment: [*Sit Up Straight, **Eat Over Your Plate**, and Don't Wipe Your Hands on Your Clothes*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22up+straight+eat+over+your+plate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: I think the correct phrasing would be "I'm dripping pizza sauce into my keyboard."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be *eating over your keyboard.* A common usage of this would be *eating over the sink* -- what you do when you're too lazy to get a plate and sit down at the table.

Comment: Eating over the sink is such a common default behavior that you might hear:  "I want to marry him, but I don't know if he can be domesticated - he's a total 'sink-eater'."